# Getting osm2pgsql usage error while installing OSM Bright for TileMill

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, postgresql-9.2, tilemill

I'm trying to install OSM Bright for TileMill, following this tutorial:
https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/osm-bright-mac-quickstart/#osm2pgsql

I installed PostGres.app + postgresql 9.2 on MAC OS X.
I've been getting this osm2pgsql error and I was wondering how to fix this:

```
osm2pgsql SVN version 0.84.0 (64bit id space)

Usage error. For further information see:
osm2pgsql -h|--help

[name]:~ [name]$ which osm2pgsql
/usr/local/bin/osm2pgsql
```

Comment: You did not give a osm2pgsql a valid set of arguments.  see 'osm2pgsql -h', or at least show us what you executed to get that error message

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide `osm2pgsql` with the proper argument(s).

> Go to http://metro.teczno.com and look for your city. If it’s available, download the .osm.pbf version of the extract.

Then you should be able to successfully run this command.

```
osm2pgsql -c -G -d osm -S /usr/local/share/osm2pgsql/default.style ~/Downloads/your_file.osm.pbf
```

Please see [Chapter 2](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/osm-bright-mac-quickstart/#step_2_download__import_osm_data) for more information on the arguments needed to download and import OSM data.